# Before insert triggert in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers

I am trying to use a trigger to insert the updated value to another table. I have two tables (table1 and table2).

I want to copy the new primary key of table1 to a non-primary key field in table2 in hexadecimal value. the primary key is integer type and the other field is varchar.

The code is as follows:

```
delimiter /

drop trigger if exists a /
create trigger a before insert on table1 for each row 

begin
 insert into table2 set table1ID= hex(new.id);
end /

insert into table1 set name='Ronnie';
```

But, the problem is when i insert into table1, the primary key will not be added to table2. it will add 0 instead.

These are the tables:

```
    create table table1 (
    id          integer         not null auto_increment primary key,
    name        varchar(45)     not null
    );

create table table2 (
    id          integer         not null auto_increment primary key,
    table1ID    varchar(45)     not null
    );
```

Comment: @GordonLinoff I fixed it thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your trigger is "before insert", and the new generated id is not available yet. Change it to "after insert":

```
create trigger a after insert on table1 for each row 
begin
 insert into table2 (warehouseID) values (hex(new.id));
end /
```

Please see it [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8d211/1).

Comment: I misunderstood the question.  I thought the OP meant the id in the second table was not being set.